# Flutter - Re ask location permission after denied

Tags: flutter, permissions, geolocation, location

I am currently using the location package to retrieve a users current location. If a user denies this request, I would like to be able to re-ask for these permissions later in the app, when their location is needed.

```
initPlatformState() async {
    await _locationService.changeSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.HIGH, interval: 1000);


  LocationData location;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      bool serviceStatus = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
      print("Service status: $serviceStatus");
      if (serviceStatus) {
        _permission = await _locationService.requestPermission();
        print("Permission: $_permission");

        if (_permission) {
          location = await _locationService.getLocation();
        }
      } else {
        bool serviceStatusResult = await _locationService.requestService();
        print("Service status activated after request: $serviceStatusResult");
        if (serviceStatusResult) {
          initPlatformState();
        }
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = e.message;
        print(error);
      } else if (e.code == 'SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR') {
        error = e.message;
        print(error);
      }
      location = null;
    }

    setState(() {
      _currentLocation = location;
    });
  }
```

The above code is run in the init state of the application, and is always executed upon first running the application.

Upon first run, when the permission screen appears everything works as expected if you grant permission, and retrieves the location as required. If you deny the permission, permission is "false", as expected. However, If you reopen the application it only ever retrieves `"Service Status: True"` and is stuck on the line

```
_permission = await _locationService.requestPermission();
```

and never progresses any further. I was expecting upon executing the above code, that the "Please share your location" screen would re-appear but it appears that because the user denied it on first launch, it wont reappear. Thus, the application cannot be used until this is changed.

Is there a way to make this message re-appear? Or do I have to direct the user to open settings and enable location permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrap your `initPlatformState()` in a setState in initState

```
      @override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  setState(() {
     initPlatformState()
  });

}
```